# How to fix Error: unexpected '=' in from rename() function with R?

Tags: r, error-handling, syntax-error, rename

I am using the following code in R to rename a column in a dataframe. But, I am getting an error. I do not understand why. I am following the examples I found online.

Can someone please let me know how to fix my code?

```
install.packages("dplyr")    
library(dplyr)    
install.packages("plyr")    
library(plyr)    
stacked_2017_final_dataset <- rename(stacked_2017_final_dataset, stacked_2017_final_dataset$M8A2C2_Scored = stacked_2017_final_dataset$Q2_Scored)
```

Comment: What examples are you following online? It's generally a bad idea to load both "dplyr" and "plyr". I might try to use a different/more up-to-date reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
plyr::rename(stacked_2017_final_dataset, c("M8A2C2_Scored" = "Q2_Scored"))
```